# open and manipulate a web form in firefox

Tags: winforms, firefox, input, dom-manipulation

I need to open a link from a winform application in a firefox browser. Then I would like to autocomplete the form's inputs (like username and password) and generate a button click (a login button to submit the form for instance).

I'm currently doing the same think with IE using Interop.SHDocVw.dll, but I need a firefox implementation.
Is there such a dll for the mozilla's broswer? Do I need to develop a plugin? or maybe I might have to use a UI testing framework?

thanks for the answers!

Bruno

Answer (score 0):

So I start Firefox using Process start:

```
Process.Start("firefox.exe", "http://www.mywebsite.com");
```

I then use USER32.DLL to find and focus on the Firefox window:

```
// Get a handle to an application window.
[DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

// Activate an application window.
[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

private void btnEnterText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var handle = FindWindow("MozillaUIWindowClass", "Environnement de recette 1.4.0.3 - Mozilla Firefox");
        SetForegroundWindow(handle);
        SendKeys.SendWait(txtEntry.Text);
    }
```

I found the window's class and title thanks to spy++.

So my problem no is to move to the next input on the page... when I use this:

```
SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
```

it moves the focus as is I pressed TAB 2 times.... Does anyone knows what's happening ?